# Language restrictions on iPhone partially lifted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, embedded, lua

Apparently Apple has changed some term in the agreement again.

From http://www.appleoutsider.com/2010/06/10/hello-lua/

section 3.3.2 is now

> Unless otherwise approved by Apple in writing, no interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s). Notwithstanding the foregoing, with Apple’s prior written consent, an Application may use embedded interpreted code in a limited way if such use is solely for providing minor features or functionality that are consistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application.

instead of the original

> No interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s).

I am more interested in embedding Lua, but other people have other embeddings they want to make.

I am wondering how you ask for permission, and what they mean by the terms "minor features" and "consistent" and how will Apple interpret this section?  It seems to have enough loopholes to drive a real firetruck through.

(BTW this is a terribly important question for me an my product.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, the ultimate interpretation of the developer agreement is up to Apple.

Since this is all new, it's not clear who to e-mail. You could start with the iTunes Connect people, but be prepared for a long wait to hear back. Alternatively, I've gotten some occasional quick help just by calling up the nice Apple people in Ireland.

Given the wording , if you want to embed Lua, you should be prepared to justify that you will be using Lua in a limited fashion to provide minor features or functionality.

Since you've stated this is a really important question, you might want to consider the risks inherent with pushing the envelope/being a pioneer. If there's an alternative way to get around all this, you should consider it. If there's no way around it, it might make more business sense for you to pursue another platform for now.